# Spring JasperReports Images Location

Tags: java, image, spring, properties, jasper-reports

JasperReport requires (by default) that images be in "WEB-INF/classes/". I'd like to share images between PDFs and normal JSP pages. I'd rather not clutter up classpath with garbage image files. How do I force JR to use a different location for images?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend creating the following report parameters:

- ROOT_DIR -- `"/reports/"`
- IMAGE_DIR -- `$P{ROOT_DIR} + "images/"`
- STYLE_DIR -- `$P{ROOT_DIR} + "styles/"`
- SUBREPORT_DIR -- `$P{ROOT_DIR} + "subreports/"`
- COMMON_DIR -- `$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "common/"`

This allows the images directory to be relative to the `ROOT_DIR` path. It also allows you to change `ROOT_DIR` dynamically. The parameters must be declared in their relative order.

In your case, using an absolute path:

- ROOT_DIR -- `"/home/user/"`
- IMAGE_DIR -- `$P{ROOT_DIR} + "Pictures/"`

Note that changing between operating systems, directory structures, environments (e.g., migrating to JasperReports Server from JasperReports & JSF) and so forth, can be accomplished without having to modify the report. (Well, some modifications are required for JasperReports Server.)

Answer (score 2):

Following @Dave's advice I split out the base directory into a Parameter and gave it a default. That way I can specify either an absolute path, classpath or url. Here are the relevant pieces of code:

Controller:

`modelMap.put("ROOT_DIR", "/srv/images/");`

-Or-

`modelMap.put("ROOT_DIR", "http://site.com/images/");`

jrxml File:

```
<parameter name="ROOT_DIR" class="java.lang.String">
    <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["/home/user/Pictures/"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
...
<imageExpression class="java.lang.String">
   <![CDATA[$P{ROOT_DIR}+"leaf_banner_red.png"]]>
</imageExpression>
```

Answer (score 1):

Upon further inspection, it doesn't seem like I can set a 'location' for images anywhere but I did find out that you can specify images 1 of 3 ways:

- Classpath: "image.png"
- Absolute: "/home/user/Pictures/image.png"
- Url: "https://encrypted.google.com/images/logos/ssl_ps_logo.png"